# Is the cross section of a relativistic water hose or string always a perfect circle?

Tags: special-relativity, string-theory, relativity

Given is a very long tube, such as a water hose or a tubular string with finite thickness, that has a constant circular cross section of radius $r$ along the length and that is at rest in an inertial frame. The hose is either

1. straight or
2. curved with radius $R$, or
3. irregularly shaped.

Is the shape of the cross section always a circle for a relativistically fast observer of velocity $v$? What is the observed cross-section radius $r(v)$ of the hose?

How does $r(v)$ depend on the geometry of the situation, i.e., on the angles between v and the hose? Is it constant along the length of the hose? The overall shape of the hose will vary for each observer. But will its radius $r(v)$ vary or not? We suspected that the cross section remains circular in all cases, and that $r(v)=r$ in all cases, for all observers, along the full length of the hose. The answer is a bit unexpected, though.

P.S. This is not homework. It is a question we discussed at lunch yesterday.

P.P.S. If the "hose" would be a string with some radius, the result might also apply to string theory?

Comment: Could you be more clear about the different cases you're trying to ask about? The angle of the relative velocity is one thing, but then you're combining that with the different shapes. It seems like this should be narrowed down to make for a better question. Or perhaps just consider one simple bend to exemplify the flow-rate issue you may have in mind.

Comment: I am looking for the geometrical cross section of the hose. There is no water in the hose!

Comment: This is something you have to explicitly calculate from the Lorentz transformation - so there is no simple answer. The maths, though, is not too hard, especially if you set up something like a Mathematica notebook. Some results are summarised nicely in the videos made at http://www.anu.edu.au/physics/Searle/#downloads . I would suggest sketching one particular geometry whose transformation you would like to investigate, and then someone can show you how to work through the calcs. For example, if you are considering the distortion of a circle, the four-vectors in a relatively stationary ....

Comment: ... frame fulfil a quadric equation of the form $X^T\, Q \,X = r^2$, so that the transformed geometry will fulfill $X^T\,\Lambda^T\,Q\,\Lambda\,X = r^2$, where $\Lambda$ is the Lorentz transformation, *i.e.* the $4\times4$ matrix representing the boost in question and $Q$ encodes the circle. So you get another equation of the same form: the circle gets shrunken in one direction more than the other.

Comment: The first case (a) is the straight hose. Such a hose corresponds to the signposts in the videos at anu.edu.au. The videos seem to imply that the signposts get distorted in shape, but that the cross section remains circular. The second case (b) is a hose of circular shape, like the tire of a wheel. I just found http://www.spacetimetravel.org/rad/rad.html and it seems that the wheel tires also keep their cross section.

Comment: Various relativity visualization pages mention that spheres remain spheres under relativistic boosts; this should mean that the shape of the cross section will remain circular, whatever the observer, the angle and the shape of the garden hose. Is this correct?

Comment: You're thinking of one of two things: 1). a spherical wave (i.e. with phase speed $c$) is a spherical wave with phase speed $c$ in all inertial frames: other phase speed spherical waves will become distorted or (2) the action of the Lorentz group on the celestial sphere: this is isomorphic to a double cover of the group of Möbius transformations and a Lorentz boost's action on the Celestial sphere can be interpreted as a conformal transformation on the Riemann sphere, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Relation_to_the_M.C3.B6bius_group - such transformations are well known to ...

Comment: ...map circles to circles. However, this is when they projected onto the celestial sphere - so a circular constellation in the night sky will be mapped onto another circular constellation in the night sky, but this is not the same thing as saying a general circle maps to a general circle. Anyhow, I'll write some equations down for you in the next couple of days if someone else doesn't do so